# Zap docker - Active scan

Tags: docker, owasp, zap

Is there a way to run active scan through ZAP docker?

I have a web application that requires login and after login I need to record the actions I am doing in UI and need to do active scan against that page. It is a form based web application.

We are using python with selenium for UI automation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, via the Full Packaged Scan: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/full-scan/
Setting up authentication is also possible - we've just published a video walking through this process: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BOlalxfdLbU